# how to use a local image as a Qicon

Tags: image, svg, quasar, qicon

I want to use githubLogo.svg as a Qicon so I did this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVwFo.png)
But it's not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUqEs.png)

I don't understand why is not working, I used the quasar doc (https://quasar.dev/vue-components/icon#introduction) and I don't what I did wrong.

Comment: try q-img and not q-icon.

Answer (score 0):

In quasar, for some reason(which i don't know) in order to bind assets dynamically to quasar components, you have to keep your images inside of "/public" directory.

Create a new folder called "images" in your project's "/public" and it should work just fine.

best of luck to you.